# Why doesn't psycopg2 respect case?

Tags: django, postgresql

In posgtresql (atleast on ubuntu server) if i create database like

```
CREATE DATABASE azREydayz;
```

And then add the same database name in django settings

```
DATABASES = {
  'ENGINE': 'postgresql_psycopg2',
  'NAME': 'azREydayz', 
}
```

i get an error saying

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "azREydayz" does not exist
```

.To solve this i change the 'NAME': 'azREydayz', to 'NAME': 'azreydayz', .
My question is why doesn't psycopg2 respect case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is [because database names are only case sensitive when quoted](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1007042494.1110.5.camel@entwicklung01.cenes.de), so if you did `CREATE DATABASE "azREydayz";` it would have respected the case.

Comment: Yep, same as everything else in PostgreSQL. Even if it's sometimes a little un-intuitive in cases like this.